# How to inject content script when the user clicks on the extension icon

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

I want to inject custom code to the web page after the user clicks on my chrome extension icon or clicks on a button inside the chrome extension popup. I have seen this feature been done in **loom **(Screen Recorder) in which when the user clicks on the loom icon, it shows a popup for loading and then injects its own custom code to the user's web page [in the image, it injects its own code inside the DOM to start recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7eAM.png)

I also want to do something like this, but not sure how exactly I should go about this,

I try this :-

**manifest.json**

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Description of my extension",
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      }
    
  }
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: "content.js"
      });
  });
```

**content.js**

```js
  const overlayButton = document.createElement("button");
  overlayButton.innerText = "Record";
  
  // Add a click event listener to the button
  overlayButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Code to handle button click event
  });
  
  // Add the overlay button to the page
  document.body.appendChild(overlayButton);
```

But I got this error in the chrome extension :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhEEI.png)

I am not really sure what is best practise to inject my own code inside the user's web page. Also how should I do it without writing the .innerHTML and the whole html inside it

Thank you :)

Comment: To use `action` you need to add `"action": {}` to manifest.json. There's also no chrome.tabs.executeScript in ManifestV3, it's chrome.scripting.executeScript and you need to add `scripting` to `permissions` in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm I added action: {} in my manifest and changed the execute script, but now when I click on the extension, nothing happen?

Comment: Debug it. [How to see background.js console?](/a/10258029) Also don't forget to click the reload icon in chrome://extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I am still trying to figure it out, but I need your advice on something, is it more useful to create the chrome extension like loom using Reactjs or with raw js, HTML and CSS?

Comment: for v3: remove content_script from manifest and in "action" add this "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon-32.png",
      "24": "images/icon-32.png",
      "32": "images/icon-32.png"
    }
  }, this will let icon to have a event and now in background.js add this code chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      files: ['content.js']
    });

  });